# Refresh RenderBody() Content with Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got an ASP.NET project using MVC 4 and Entity Framework with the following structure:

```
-Controllers
    -HomeController.cs
    -SystemInformationController.cs

-Views
    -Home
        -Index.cshtml
    -Shared
        -MasterLayout.cshtml
    -SystemInformation
        -Index.cshtml
```

The MasterLayout.cshtml code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Site</title>
    <link href="~/Content/MasterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="TopContent">
        <a>Home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="LeftContent">
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "basiclink" })
    <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("System Information", "Index", "SystemInformation", new { @class = "basiclink" })
    <br />
</div>
<div id="MainContent">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

The Index.cshtml code for the Home view is as follows:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterLayout.cshtml";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Welcome to the Sample Site.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am having is that whenever I click on either link, be it the home link or the system information link, the url simply appends a "?length=X" where X is the length of the third parameter in the ActionLink item.  I want to have the content held within the Master Page to be refreshed but no matter what I do the URL seems to be built incorrectly and not refreshing the center content.  Anyone have any ideas as to why that is happening?

Comment: For starters, you're emitting very malformed HTML.  Your content view should just be the *content* of the page, not an entire page structure.  Putting html/head/body tags inside of a `div` might confuse the browser.  As for the actual problem you're seeing, what are the resulting anchor tags rendered by these action links?  Is there any JavaScript that's overriding the click events for them?

Comment: @David
There is nothing overriding the click events. The reason why I was using a full page is because I thought that using Razor and cshtml required a full page design. Could I just design it as a partial page like you suggested? The anchor tags that are rendered are as follows:

`<a class="basiclink" href="/?Length=4">Home</a>`

`<a class="basiclink" href="/?Length=17">System Information</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using a different overload of the ActionLink method than you probably want.  The one you are using is taking your third parameter and using it as the route values, not the controller name.  Try changing your links to this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {}, new { @class = "basiclink" })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response.  It does exactly what I need it to do now.  Out of curiosity, what is the route value that I can put in there now?

Comment: Route values are used to pass something like arguments to your pages.  So say you have a page that shows detailed product information (/Products/Details).  You wouldn't want to make a new action and page for every product.  Rather you would use a route value, like a product id, and reuse the page.  You would use something like 'Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Products", new { id = 10 }, new { @class = "basiclink" })' to get a link like /Products/Details/10.  Then each product link would just change the route value to show the information for a different product.

Comment: For something like your /Home/Index page, you probably don't need any route values.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the explanation.  It's been very helpful in getting me moving forward on this application.